# pdf file with python

Tags: python, file, pdf, cpu-word, line

How can search a word or a line in a pdf file?

Is there an existing module to do that by being concise?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something called as [pyPDF.](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/)
It is a `Pure-Python` library built as a `PDF toolkit.`

You can extract ( using `extractText()` method ) & also perform search on the pdf file with using something like following code.

```
pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
content = pdf.getPage(1).extractText()
```